# How do I change the web-site name from admin panel in php?

Tags: php

I am creating a new site and I am wondering if it is possible to change the site name from the admin panel? I searched a lot but could not find it. I have not written any code for this yet

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>registration</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- favicon -->        
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/logo/favicon.ico">

    <!-- all css here -->

    <!-- bootstrap v3.3.6 css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- font-awesome css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- style css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- responsive css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">

    <!-- modernizr css -->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

After `<title>registration {here site name}</title>` I want the site name to be written automatically. I have the file in PHP of course. Is it possible to do this without Laravel?

Comment: You can store and fetch the site name from the database server

Comment: I think I realized I need to create a site name table and write it in a php tag after registering?

Comment: What keeps you from modifying the given code?

Comment: I do not know how to use Laraveli unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is create a settings table that contains all the site information which will queried and displayed on the site.

Comment: Yes, now I understand what and how to do it. thank you